# Binding to a UIElement's property from a static resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've built a filtering `Behavior` for `CollectionViewSource`, it generally works and is used like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ListOfStuff}"  x:Key="FilteredListOfStuff">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:FilterBehavior>
            <behaviors:PropertyFilter Property="SomePropName">
                <behaviors:TextFilter FilterText="filter text"/>
            </behaviors:PropertyFilter>
        </behaviors:FilterBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

The problem is that, as I now realize, I can't bind filter properties to UIElements because the `CollectionViewSource` is a static resource.

What I wanted, and now can't, do is this:

```
<behaviors:TextFilter FilterText="{Binding ElementName=TheSearchTextBox, Path=Text}"/>
```

Is there a way around this? My filtering behavior is based on using the `CollectionViewSource.Filter` event, is there a good and clean way to filter without 'CollectionViewSource'? That is, add a filter behavior directly to `ItemsControl`s (DataGrid, ListBox, etc.)?

I can solve this by binding `TheSearchTextBox.Text` and `FilterText` to the same ViewModel property, but this sort of breaks MVVM as the filtering is a purely "View" action...

**EDIT**
Adding the filter behavior code:

```
    [ContentPropertyAttribute("Filters")]
    public class FilterBehavior : Behavior<CollectionViewSource>
    {

        private List<IFilter> _filters;
        public List<IFilter> Filters
        {
            get
            {
                return _filters ??
                            (_filters = new List<IFilter>());
            }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.Filter += CollectionViewSource_Filter;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.Filter -= CollectionViewSource_Filter;
        }

        void CollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Filters != null)
            {
                e.Accepted = Filters.All((f) => !f.IsEnabled || f.Filter(e.Item));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why does the 'CollectionViewSource' have to be a static resource? I assume that, as you want to bind to some visual tree element, you will use it only once? So you could define it directly in the visual tree, where binding should work.

Comment: Can you post your Behavior's code ? You can directly insert Behavior in the Control where it is needed.

Comment: You can always use Mode=OneWay to send value from TextBox to your staticresource, if your StaticResource is a DepObject.

Comment: @LionAM That would be a good solution, but how do I specify the `CollectionViewSource` directly on the element

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I've added the `FilterBehavior` code, it's quite simple, all i need is the `CollectionViewSource`... I've tried `Mode=OneWay` but I still get: `System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextFilter'; target property is 'FilterText' (type 'String')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need user supplied filter string in our `FilterText` property of `behaviors:TextFilter` class.

Create a simple class FilterPropertyElement :

```
    public class FilterPropertyElement : FrameworkElement
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Tag.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Declare the resource

```
<Window.Resources>
         <local:FilterPropertyElement x:Key="FilterPropertyKey" Tag="some filter key value"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Change your TextFilter definition to use the Resource. :

```
<behaviors:TextFilter FilterText="{Binding Path=Tag, Source={StaticResource FilterPropertyKey}}"/>
```

Apply binding to the TextBox from where to get filter criteria

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Tag, Source={StaticResource FilterPropertyKey}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

Comment: Ok, So I didn't do exactly what you suggested, but close enough to accept the answer. I'll write the details of what I did in another answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing, inspired by AnjumSKhan's answer, was to add the filter to the rood `Resources` collection and have the `TextBox` bind to it:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <b:TextFilter x:Key="SearchTextFilter" />
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ListOfStuff}"  x:Key="FilteredListOfStuff">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <b:FilterBehavior>
                <b:PropertyFilter Property="SomePropName">
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="SearchTextFilter"/>
                </b:PropertyFilter>
            </b:FilterBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
.
.
.
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FilterText, Source={StaticResource SearchTextFilter}, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

This is still not as clean as I'd like, but it's the best I can come up with, if anyone got a better solution please let me know.